# Is there any way to ignore a property in class if it's null when insert data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, insert

```
class a
{
  public string a { get; set; }
  public string b { get; set; }
  public string c { get; set; }
}
```

if a is null

I want to ignore it, like BsonIgnoreIfNull in MongDB

Comment: What does this code have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: Since you don't insert class (instances) directly into SQL Server, I'm unclear what you're asking. Also, what do you mean by *ignore*? If we assume that there's a table that contains 3 identically defined columns for `a`, `b` and `c` and we're "ignoring" `a` because it's `null`, what are we expecting to insert into the column called `a`?

Comment: you must show your code where you triggering inert statement ..

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You're comparing two very different types of data storage systems. SQL Server is a *relational database*<sup>1</sup>. In relational databases, all rows in a particular table will have values (or `null`s) for *all* columns defined by the table.

In contrast, MongoDB is a *document database*. It stores documents (in collections) and each document may have *different* fields defined within it. This is often described as a "schema-less" system (in contrast to a relational database) precisely because of this variability.

---

<sup>1</sup>Roughly. It's the SQL interpretation of relational.